# Finding Token un WHMCS

Tags: whmcs

I'm making a module in WHMCS and I am in need of the Token identifier to send a request to WHMCS internally, a page. But I've tried the session but that's not the token:

```
$_SESSION['tkval'];
```

Any idea how to get the current WHMCS token in a module for use inside the system?

Answer (score 2):

If you're reading from php file (e.g. addon or hook):

```
$smartyObj = $GLOBALS['smarty'];
$formToken = $smartyObj->get_template_vars('token');
```

Comment: Nope, I get this error `Fatal error: Call to a member function get_template_vars()`

Comment: in which function in the module you're trying to get the token?

Comment: My module only has one function `_output`. That's where I'm calling it.

Comment: yes, it is not available in the _output. I just checked the $GLOBALS variable. does the action to requires to send the token is taken after full page load? may be you can read it using javascript? every form has hidden input named token.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of module are you making? If the page already has a form with a token, then grabbing that would be the best bet (via the smarty object if you can get access to it or via JS inspecting a hidden form field.) However is this an addon module or some other pages where the content you are rendering does not contain a CRSF token then you can't really scrape and re-use it.

Instead of submitting to a CRSF validated in most cases I would look at using the API or data models to make the changes. Docs for the API:

http://docs.whmcs.com/API

and for public data models:

http://docs.whmcs.com/classes/namespaces/WHMCS.html

If you have to have a CRSF token and the page does not offer one, then you are kinda stuck. I would recommend making a feature request for an API command to give you a CRSF token:

https://requests.whmcs.com/